# A suggestion for a Fortran IDE?

Tags: development, ide

I just installed gfortran on my Mac OS X 10.8.5, and now I need an IDE in order to write and compile and run my fortran programs. I used to use Codeblocks in Ubuntu, but I prefer to ask for an optimal IDE for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an Eclipse extension for Fortran, aptly called [Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/). It should run fine on the Mac.